# How do I make Xcode open .h first rather than .m files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When creating a new class in Xcode the default behaviour is to open and display the implementation file (.m). How do I make Xcode open the header (.h) file first? I often find myself often needing to alter the .h file first to change things such as member variables, properties and inheritance.

Comment: I don't think you can do that easily, but you can switch to the header quickly by pressing ctrl+cmd+up-arrow.

Answer (score 1):

As you add a new class, the first file that gets added is .h and last file is .m.

And XCode opens the latest file for you which is .m. Now you want to make it reverse, which is not possible unless some tweak or hack, but the best practice would be to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> to switch between .h and .m